# Evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{T} e^{-xt} \cos t \,dt$

Tags: integration

I am circling in rounds by evaluating the following integral:
$$J=\int_{0}^{T} e^{-xt} \cos t\, dt$$ where $x \to \infty$ and $T>0$

I started by integrating by parts. 
$$\int_{0}^{T} e^{-xt} \cos t\, dt = \bigg[\frac{-1}{x}e^{-xt}\cos t \bigg]_0^T- \int_{0}^{T} \frac{1}{x}e^{-xt} \sin t \,dt$$
But in stead of easier it became harder. I don't think a substitution is possible, but perhaps I am wrong.

Can anybody give me some help?

Comment: Do it by parts once more.

Comment: If $x\to\infinity$, wouldn't you just integrating $0$ since $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-x} = 0$?

Comment: Perhaps he meant $T\to \infty$ as one would do in a laplace transform

Comment: Joe Doldiamond:  clarification really is needed here---do you mean to take $x\to\infty$ or $T\to\infty$?  The answer to your question depends very much on which limit you intend to take?

Comment: The conditions that were mentioned: $x \rightarrow \infty$ and $T>0$. I didn’t mean to use a limit.

Comment: If $x\to\infty$ is not meant to denote any kind of limit, what **does** it mean?  Do you simply want to assert that $x > 0$?  or that $x$ is some arbitrary large number?  I am now quite confused.

Comment: I had to apply Watson's lemma  to this integral, and I wanted to compare the results of both ways. My apologies for the confusion. Could there be a difference when T tends to finity and infinity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least three methods spring to mind:

1. Using integration by parts, we have
   \begin{align}
   J &= \int_{0}^{T} \mathrm{e}^{-xt}\cos(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \\
   &= \left.-\frac{1}{x}\cos(t)\mathrm{e}^{-xt}\right|_{t=0}^{T} - \frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{T} \mathrm{e}^{-xt}\sin(t)\,\mathrm{d}t && \text{(IBP)} \\
   &= -\frac{1}{x} \cos(T)\mathrm{e}^{-xT} + \frac{1}{x} - \left( \left. -\frac{1}{x^2} \sin(t) \mathrm{e}^{-xt} \right|_{t=0}^{T} 
    + \frac{1}{x}^2 \int_{0}^{T} \mathrm{e}^{-xt} \cos(t) \,\mathrm{d}t \right) &&\text{(IBP again)} \\
   &= -\frac{1}{x} \cos(T)\mathrm{e}^{-xT} + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2}\sin(T)\mathrm{e}^{-xT} - \frac{1}{x^2} J.
   \end{align}
   Solving for $J$, we obtain
   \begin{align}
   &\left( 1 + \frac{1}{x^2} \right) J
   = \left( \frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2} \right)
   = -\frac{1}{x} \cos(T)\mathrm{e}^{-xT} + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2}\sin(T)\mathrm{e}^{-xT} \\
   &\qquad\implies J = -\frac{x}{x^2+1}\cos(T)\mathrm{e}^{-xT} + \frac{x}{x^2+1} + \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} \sin(T)\mathrm{e}^{-xT}.
   \end{align}
   Since both $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\mathrm{e}^{-xT}$ go to zero as $x \to \infty$, it follows that $\lim_{x\to\infty} J = 0$.

   The downside to this approach, I think, is that there is a lot of computation, which means that there are a lot of places where we can make mistakes.  Indeed, I am not entirely certain that all of my computations are correct (I found two mistakes while typing my handwritten notes into the answer box—it seems reasonable to conclude that there are other mistakes still remaining).  I'm sure that the basic order estimates are correct, but the exact formula for $J$ scares me a bit.

   > If, on the other hand, the goal is to take $T\to\infty$, the fact that
   >   $$ \lim_{T\to\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-xT} = 0 $$
   >   gives us
   >   $$ J
   > = -\frac{x}{x^2+1}\cos(T)\mathrm{e}^{-xT} + \frac{x}{x^2+1} + \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} \sin(T)\mathrm{e}^{-xT}
   > = \frac{x}{x^2+1}. $$
2. We can use the fact that
   $$ \cos(t) = \frac{\mathrm{e^{it} + \mathrm{e}^{-it}}}{2} $$
   and integrate.  Via this approach, we have
   \begin{align}
   J
    &= \int_{0}^{T} \mathrm{e}^{-xT}\cos(t) \,\mathrm{d}t \\
    &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{T} \mathrm{e}^{-xt} \left( \mathrm{e}^{it} + \mathrm{e}^{-it} \right)\,\mathrm{d}t \\
    &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{T} \mathrm{e}^{(-x+i)t} + \mathrm{e}^{(-x-i)t}\,\mathrm{d}t \\
    &= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{1}{-x+i} \mathrm{e}^{(-x+i)t} + \frac{1}{-x-i} \mathrm{e}^{(-x-i)t} \right|_{t=0}^{T} \\
    &= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{1}{i-x} \mathrm{e}^{(i-x)T} - \frac{1}{x+i} \mathrm{e}^{-(x+i) T} - \frac{1}{i-x} + \frac{1}{x+i} \right].
   \end{align}
   Again, taking $x\to \infty$, this goes to zero.  Unfortunately, there is still a great deal of computation, and it is easy to make mistakes, though we do avoid two integration by parts steps, which makes me more confident about the result.  Note that the exact formula for $J$ looks different, but after simplification, I'm sure that (in particular) all of the $i$s will fall out and we'll get something recognizable.

   > Again, if the goal is to take $T\to\infty$, the exponential terms decay to zero, and we get
   >   \begin{align}\lim_{T\to\infty} J
   > &= \lim_{T\to\infty} \frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{1}{i-x} \mathrm{e}^{(i-x)T} - \frac{1}{x+i} \mathrm{e}^{-(x+i) T} - \frac{1}{i-x} + \frac{1}{x+i} \right] \\
   > &= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{1}{x+i} + \frac{1}{x-i} \right] \\
   > &= \frac{1}{2} \frac{(x-i) + (x+i)}{(x+i)(x-i)} \\
   > &= \frac{1}{2} \frac{2x}{x^2 + 1} \\
   > &= \frac{x}{x^2+1},
   > \end{align}
   >   which is exactly what we got above.
3. I think that the best approach to this problem is to apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem.  On the interval $[0,T]$, the function
   $$ f(t) = \mathrm{e}^{-xt} \cos(t) $$
   is bounded by $1$ for any $x > 0$.  That is,
   $$ |f(t)|
   = \left| \mathrm{e}^{-xt} \cos(t) \right|
   = \left| \mathrm{e}^{-xt} \right| |\cos(t)|
   \le \left| \mathrm{e}^{0} \right|
   = 1. $$
   Since $\int_{0}^{T} 1 \,\mathrm{d}t = T < \infty$, we can apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem in order to conclude that
   $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{T} \mathrm{e}^{-nt}\cos(t) \,\mathrm{d}t
   = \int_{0}^{T} \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \mathrm{e}^{-nt}\cos(t) \right) \,\mathrm{d}t, $$
   where $n$ is a positive integer.  But
   $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \mathrm{e}^{-nt}\cos(t) \right) = 0 $$
   for all $t \in [0,T]$, so we have
   $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} J
   = \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{T} \mathrm{e}^{-nt}\cos(t) \,\mathrm{d}t
   = \int_{0}^{T} 0 \,\mathrm{d}t
   = 0. $$
   This approach is nice in that there is very little computation, but there is a detail that I have elided, namely that I have only proved the result for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, not for $x\in[0,\infty)$.  However, the argument can be modified to make it rigorous with out *too* much difficulty.

   > Note that this approach doesn't help if we are trying to take $T\to\infty$.

Comment: +1 for the through and complete answer

Answer (score 1):

$J=\int_{0}^{T} e^{-xt} \cos (t) \,dt$

integrating by parts gives;

$J =e^{-xt}\cdot\sin(t)\bigg|_0^T+\int_0^T\frac{e^{-xt}}{x}\,\cos(t)\,dt $

integrate $\int_0^T\frac{e^{-xt}}{x}\,\cos(t)\,dt$ by parts once again;

$J = e^{-xt}\cdot\sin(t)\bigg|_0^T-\frac{e^{-xt}}{x}\,\cos(t)\bigg|_0^T-\int_0^T\frac{e^{-xt}}{x^2}\,\cos(t)\,dt$

$J =e^{-xt}\cdot\sin(t)\bigg|_0^T-\frac{e^{-xt}}{x}\,\cos(t)\bigg|_0^T-\frac{1}{x^2}J$

$J\bigg[1+\frac1{x^2}\bigg] = e^{-xT}\cdot\sin(T)-\frac{e^{-xT}}{x}\cdot\cos(T)+\frac1x$

$J =\dfrac{ e^{-xT}\cdot\sin(T)-\frac{e^{-xT}}{x}\cdot\cos(T)+\frac1x}{1+\frac1{x^2}}$

NOTE:

I am going to assume you meant $T\to \infty$, and proceed further,

$J = \lim_{T\to\infty}\bigg[\dfrac{ e^{-xT}\cdot\sin(T)-\frac{e^{-xT}}{x}\cdot\cos(T)+\frac1x}{1+\frac1{x^2}}\bigg]$

$J = \bigg[\dfrac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{x^2+1}{x^2}}\bigg]$

$J = \dfrac x{x^2+1}$

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your $x\to\infty$ under the integral notation. Maybe you mean $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ after computing the integral?

One can solve these type of integrals using complex numbers, because of $e^{iy}=\cos(y)+i\sin(y)$.

Define $$J' =\int_{0}^{T} e^{-xt} \sin t\, dt$$
so that

$$J+iJ' = \int_{0}^{T} e^{-xt}e^{it} \, dt =  \int_{0}^{T} e^{(-x+i)t} \, dt = \frac{e^{(-x+i)T}-1}{-x+i}$$
and now extract 
$$J = \operatorname{Re}\bigg(\frac{e^{(-x+i)T}-1}{-x+i}\bigg)= \frac{x}{1+x^2}  - \frac{e^{-Tx}x\cos(T)}{1+x^2}+\frac{e^{-Tx}\sin(x)}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: The $x \rightarrow 0$ was just a condition, It was not my purpose to suggest Some sort of limit. Sorry for this inconvinience.